# "Atop" versus "on top of"

Tags: grammaticality, differences

I'm sure this is silly and won't be terribly difficult to answer: can one climb atop a mountain or is it proper to say climb on top of. Or does it matter?  I'm thinking the latter is correct.

Comment: It's _versus_, not _verses_. And it's pronounced with a final S, not a Z. And neither one of those is correct. _On top of_ and _atop_ both mean situated on the top, not moving up the slope.

Comment: One can *stand* atop, or on top of, something, but not *climb* atop.

Comment: @Mark: Of course you can - 100 writers in Google Books say someone ["climbed atop the wall"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22climbed+atop+the+wall%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting, and given your evidence I must concur. Learn something new about this tongue of ours every day!

Comment: @Mark: To be honest, I thought *atop* was a quaint/fading/poetic usage, but apparently it's new(ish) and [particularly taking off in the US](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=climbed+atop+the%2Cclimbed+on+top+of+the&year_start=1910&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=). Weird.

Comment: @FF That's a particular (directional rather than locative) usage.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you would do either of these to a mountain, you would simply climb a mountain. Otherwise, they're interchangeable but *atop* is less used. Humpty Dumpty might sit atop a wall, but most other people would sit on top of one.

Comment: True, you wouldn't *climb atop* a mountain. But although I don't know exactly how he did it, Humpty Dumpty must have climbed atop the wall in order to sit on it. Unless he was lowered onto it by a crane. So far as I know, Lewis Carroll never actually told us how he got up there in the first place.

Comment: Fair comment, though I was using it as an illustration that 'atop' is more whimsical

Comment: Yeah - *atop* is definitely a bit dated/poetic. Not really in the "standard" spoken lexicon for many people - we mostly say *on top of* now.

Answer (score 3):

The standard idiom is that *one climbs **to the top of** a mountain*.

Comment: True, you don't often *climb atop a mountain* - because it's just too big. But plenty of people have ["climbed atop a table"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22climbed+atop+a+table%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I think it's inherent in climbing *atop* something that you get higher up and can thus see further. But I'm not sure climbers go up *serious* mountains for the view.