# Interchangeability between atop and on top of

Tags: word-usage

Atop seems to be used interchangeably with on top of when in sentences such as atop(/on top of) a mountain, as a preposition. However, is it correct if I use it to replace on top of in the sentence below?

This provides greater utility, on top of comfort.

I would greatly appreciate a detailed answer, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Related: ['Atop' versus 'on top of'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96641/atop-versus-on-top-of).

Answer (score 1):

You should not say

> This provides greater utility, atop of comfort.

because **atop** means *physically* on the top of, whereas your intended meaning is something like "in addition to".

The entry in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/atop) says

> **atop**
>   PREPOSITION
>   literary
>
> On the top of.
>   *the weathervane is perched atop the Great Tower*

---

> **atop**
>   ADVERB
>   literary
>
> On the top.
>   *the air-raid siren atop of the County Courthouse*

---

The indication *literary* means that the word isn't used much in spoken English.

Comment: M-W supplies example sentences where _atop_ is used metaphorically. I think the major advice is (a) rare, dated/literary, and rarer in the UK (CED) // (b) even rarer in metaphorical usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth as a BrE speaker, I have never known of **atop** to be used metaphorically.

Comment: @WeatherVane *His most recent eureka moment sits atop all of his others ideas, dominating his thoughts.*

Comment: 'Aguero ... the lethal striker, who now sits atop the Premier League scoring ranks this season alongside Mohamed Salah with 17 strikes.' [[Express.co.uk/sport/football](https://www.express.co.uk/sport/football/1085254/Mike-Dean-Sergio-Aguero-hat-trick-match-ball-Chelsea)] As a Brit (though not recognising a well-defined 'BrE') I can't remember the last time I heard someone use or read someone using  'atop'. (Note that I agree that 'This provides greater utility, atop of comfort' is best avoided.) There are degrees of 'metaphoricity'; 'atop of' meaning 'in addition to' is more peripheral.